# How to keep the old line text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to figure out this but with no success . What I am trying to do is to keep the old text while the script adds the new text below the old text.

```
public GameObject Text_Object;
private Text textComponent;
void Start () 
{
    //gets the text UI Object in canvas component
    textComponent = Text_Object.GetComponent<Text>();
    textComponent.text = "Hello";
    Text2();
}

void Text2()
{
    textComponent.text = "Hey";
}
```

Basically as you can see the first text gets replace with the second text. What I'm trying to do keep the old text while if I press T it prints the new text below the old text and also add a command when they hit D it clears the text new and old text.
[Image of what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ok3Y.png)

UPDATED

```
public GameObject Text_Object;
private Text textComponent;

void AppendText(string text)
{
    string current = textComponent.text;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(current) || current.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        current = text;
    }
    else
    {
        current += string.Format("\r\n{1}", text);
    }
    textComponent.text = current;
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    textComponent = Text_Object.GetComponent<Text>();
    textComponent.text ="Hello1";
    Welcome ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        textComponent.text = string.Empty;
    }
}

void Welcome (){
    textComponent.text = "Hello";
    textComponent.text = "Hello2";

}
```

Updated again

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Text_Object;
    private Text textComponent;

    void AppendText(string text)
    {
        textComponent = Text_Object.GetComponent<Text>();
        string current = textComponent.text;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(current) || current.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            current = text;
        }
        else
        {
            current += string.Format("\r\n{1}", text);
        }
        textComponent.text = current;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        AppendText ("Hmm");
        AppendText ("Hi");
        AppendText ("Hello");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
            textComponent.text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a string variable to store the old text before replacing with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Your question seems a little unclear for me but if I'm right you want something like this:

```
void Text2()
{
    textComponent.text += "\nHey";
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think so, I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can just make method `AppendText` then format your input parameter and append it to the current text :

```
void AppendText(string text)
{
    string current = textComponent.text;
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(current))
    {
        current = text;
    }
    else
    {
        current += string.Format("\r\n{1}", text);
    }
    textComponent.text = current;
}
```

Now all you have to do is to call `AppendText` method :

```
AppendText("hello");
AppendText("world");
AppendText("!");
```

Result should look like :

```
hello
world
!
```

**EDIT :**

*( In case of error message `System.string does not contain a definition for IsNullOrWhiteSpace` )*

Instead of :

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(current))
```

Use :

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(current) || current.Trim().Length == 0)
```

*( To clear the text )*

You can create a method that can be then pinned on to the `UnityEvent` :

```
public void ClearText()
{
    textComponent.text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: That's more like it, Thanks also how would you clear the texts if you press a button? Sorry I know this is another question

Comment: System.string does not contain a definition for IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: Thanks mate, you have been a great help!

Comment: Just found out, that it only print the last one text and not the previous texts, why?

Comment: Just edit my question script for you to look at the code if you want? Thanks

Comment: @Johnny You've created that method but you don't use it. Everywhere where you have `textComponent.text ="<something>";` you should replace with `AppendText("<something>");`